# Is there a way to set the text alignment of entire column in a table?

Tags: html, css, firefox, alignment, css-tables

Is there a simple way to set the text alignment of all cells in the second column to `right`?

Or is the only way is to set the alignment for each cell in the column?

(Unfortunately, the `align` attribute of the `col` tag is not supported in Firefox.)

Comment: Well, the modern approach _should_ be the [column combinator (`||`)](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Column_combinator), but it’s not supported in any browser yet.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Add a class to every cell in the 2nd column.

```
.second {
   text-align: right;
}
```

You could also use CSS3.

```
tr td:nth-child(2) { /* I don't think they are 0 based */
   text-align: right;
}
```

(It won't work in <= IE8)

Comment: You probably mean to every cell in the second column. That's what I though to do. I just wonder if there is a nicer way...

Comment: CSS3 allow to do it in a nicer way, but it is not supported in all browsers for now.

Comment: If you use `tr td:first-child + td { text-align:right; }` it will work on IE<=8.

Comment: @Cthulhu Wow! Do you have this as an answer somewhere? I want to upvote it.

Comment: @MrLister Actually you can find that same answer below, from smarcaurele. Thank you anyway.

Comment: @Cthulhu OK. But that answer doesn't mention that it works in IE8, which was the whole reason for me to go looking! (Call me stupid, but I never realised that if a certain browser doesn't handle `:nth-child(3)`, it may still handle `:first-child + * + *` correctly.)

Comment: @MrLister Yes, I've been using `:first-child + *` for a few years and never had problems with IE8. `first-child` doesn't work in IE7 if the first element is an HTML comment though, it's the only bug I've found.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to work with `colspan`s.

Comment: @anton What is the better CSS3 way?

Answer (score 22):

While not particularly elegant, I like to toss something like this in my site-wide css file:

```
.tr1 td:nth-child(1), .tr1 th:nth-child(1),
.tr2 td:nth-child(2), .tr2 th:nth-child(2),
.tr3 td:nth-child(3), .tr3 th:nth-child(3),
.tr4 td:nth-child(4), .tr4 th:nth-child(4),
.tr5 td:nth-child(5), .tr5 th:nth-child(5),
.tr6 td:nth-child(6), .tr6 th:nth-child(6),
.tr7 td:nth-child(7), .tr7 th:nth-child(7),
.tr8 td:nth-child(8), .tr8 th:nth-child(8),
.tr9 td:nth-child(9), .tr9 th:nth-child(9) { text-align:right }

.tc1 td:nth-child(1), .tc1 th:nth-child(1),
.tc2 td:nth-child(2), .tc2 th:nth-child(2),
.tc3 td:nth-child(3), .tc3 th:nth-child(3),
.tc4 td:nth-child(4), .tc4 th:nth-child(4),
.tc5 td:nth-child(5), .tc5 th:nth-child(5),
.tc6 td:nth-child(6), .tc6 th:nth-child(6),
.tc7 td:nth-child(7), .tc7 th:nth-child(7),
.tc8 td:nth-child(8), .tc8 th:nth-child(8),
.tc9 td:nth-child(9), .tc9 th:nth-child(9) { text-align:center }
```

Then just specify which column numbers you want center or right aligned, i.e. if you want column 2 & 7 right aligned, and 3 centered, just do:

```
<table class="tr2 tc3 tr7">
```

While the CSS isn't super elegant, the alternatives are even less elegant: i.e. a custom class for each table, or requiring each `tr` to have a `class="ralign"` or similar.

[Doesn't work with IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel3)

Comment: That's actually pretty elegant. I was looking for something like this, and am kicking myself for not having thought of it myself.

Comment: How about using "tr >" to handle both TD and TH tags? You can replace each `.tr1 td:nth-child(1), .tr1 th:nth-child(1)` with `.tr1 tr > :nth-child(1)` to reduce it by 50%.

Comment: @GarlandPope if I'm not mistaken, that wouldn't work in IE11 (and a couple other browsers) https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_selectors_nth-child_no_parent_required

Answer (score 15):

I believe that the following would work and not require annotating the second cell of each row with a class.

```
td:first-child + td { text-align: right; }
```

This rule would select a td immediately following a td that is the first child of its parent.  In a typical table this would select the second cell in each row.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but I just had this issue myself so thought I'd share a resolution. It's worth noting that this answer is only applicable if you are using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/).

Instead of having to manually add the class or style to each cell you can use loops in LESS to create a range of classes that you can apply to your tables:

```
// Loop for @i until @i = @n
// Much like - for($i=0; $i<=$n; $i++)
//
.table-cols(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n)
{
    .table-center-col-@{i}
    {
        tr > td:nth-child(@{i})
        {
            text-align: center;
        }
    }

    .table-right-col-@{i}
    {
        tr > td:nth-child(@{i})
        {
            text-align: right;
        }
    }

    // Continue the iteration
    .table-cols(@n, (@i + 1));
}

.table-cols(16);
```

This will produce a load of classes such as `.table-center-col-1` all the way up to `.table-center-col-16` (in this example) and they will make center the text of the applicable column. It will also do the same for right-aligned text, with `.table-right-col-n`.

You can adjust the number supplied (from 16) to anything to ensure that it covers you for the max amount of columns you may have in a table. For variable column numbers this won't be much help to you.

Then all you have to do is apply it to the table:

```
<table class="table-center-col-4">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Column 1</td>
            <td>Column 2</td>
            <td>Column 3</td>
            <td>Column 4</td>
            <td>Column 5</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
            <td>x</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

All of the cells in the 4th column will now have centered text.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the simplest way:
If you have a three column table & a footer of two cell like me then you can apply the below rule:

```
tr td:nth-child(3),tfoot tr td:nth-child(2){
    text-align:center;
}
```

I know this is very old question. But as a beginner, sometimes ago I faced the same problem & I have solved this like this way.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a class to every cell or cell in a row in second column will work.

```
.second {
   text-align: right;
}
```

*or*

add class to tr and add the following css in your style sheet.

```
tr.second {
   text-align: right;
}
```